Is there a analytical solution to this Quantum mechanics realted integral?
I've simplified the integral a bit combining constants and the like to make it more aproachable mathamatically.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} x^n e^{-(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+sx)}dx
$$
Where n is a positive integer and s is strictly positive. The integral comes from integrating the Gammow factor, the likely hood a particle tunnels through a coulomb barrier, over a maxwellian distribution over energy. My initial attempt was just to take a series in the exponential of the inverse square root and integrate. You quickly relize that the negetive intager powers of n lead to infinities that I don't know how to reconcile. Mathamatica will tell me that it is equal too the Meijer-G function...
$$
4^{-(n+1)}\pi^{-1/2}G_{0,3}^{3,0}\left(-;\; -(n+1), -(n+1/2), 0;\; s/4 \right)
$$
I am fairly unfamiliar with this function but I'm fairly certain that in this form at least it diverges. Either way im absolutly certain that the integral converges, but it seems to be tricky in an odd manner, anyway I come at it I get lead into road blocks. Any help would be great.

can you rescale the $s$ away, or at least symmetrize somehow? a saddle point expansion around the peak seems a possibility

alternatively, get the $x^n$ term by differentiating the s

I'm not sure about a nice closed form. Asymptotic gives
$$I(s)=\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-(\frac1{\sqrt x}+sx)}dx\sim\sqrt\frac \pi3,2^{\frac23(1-n)}s^{-\frac{2n}3-\frac56}e^{-3(s/4)^{1/3}}, ,s^{1/3}\gg1$$
$$I(s)\sim\frac1{s^{n+1}}\left(\Gamma(n+1)-\sqrt s,\Gamma\Big(n+\frac12\Big)+\frac s2\Gamma(n)+O(s^{3/2})\right),,s\ll1, ,n>0$$

@Svyatoslav How did you arrive at these expression?

At $s^\frac13\gg1$
$$I(s)\overset{x=\frac t{s^{2/3}}}{=}s^{\frac23(n+1)}\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-s^{1/3}(\frac1{\sqrt t}+t)}dt$$
and then use the Laplace method - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method . At $s\ll1$
$$I(s)\overset{x=\frac ts}{=}\frac1{s^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-(\frac {\sqrt s}{\sqrt t}+t)}dt=\frac1{s^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-t}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt s}{\sqrt t}+\frac s {2t}-...\right)dt$$
and integration term by term.

Sorry, there is a typo - should be $..=s^{\color{red}{-}\frac 23(n+1)}\int...$ in the first expression

Using Mathematica, for large $s$, ask for the series expansion

At $n=0$ and $s\to 0$ $$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac1{\sqrt x}-sx}dx=\frac1s-\frac {\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt s}-\frac{\ln s}2+\frac32(1-\gamma)+o(1)$$

Using Mathematica and negative integers: Table[(4^(-1 - n)      MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{0, -1 - n, -(1/2) - n}, {}}, s/4])/    Sqrt[\[Pi]] /. s -> 1, {n, -5, -1}] // N give me: {9845.73, 228.791, 10.5343, 1.18644, 0.373857}.I don't see any infinities ?

Let's first get rid of the square root in the integrand:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} 2x^{2n+1} e^{-(\frac{1}{x}+sx^2)}dx$$
Here we can use the fact that the integrand
$$y(x)=2x^{2n+1} e^{-(\frac{1}{x}+sx^2)}$$
has a sharp maximum.
In this case, we can use a ready-made formula, so to speak, "off the shelf":
$$I\approx \sqrt{-\frac{2\pi y^3(x_{m})}{ \frac{d^2 y(x_{m}) }{d x^2}}}$$
where $x_{m}$ is the maximum value of the integrand
The minus sign under the square root is because at the maximum point
$$\frac{d^2 y(x_{m}) }{d x^2}<0$$
The derivation of this approximate formula is too long to present here.
I believe it is covered in many relevant guides.
Next, we calculate the maximum point $x_{m}$  of the integrand.
By equating the derivative of the integrand to zero, we arrive at a cubic equation:
$$2sx^3-(2n+1)x-1=0$$
The solutions of this equation can be presented in closed form in elementary functions.
I just took some random parameters $n=5,s=2$
The cubic equation gives the maximum point at $x_{m}=1.70202$
The exact value of the integral is $I=1.02118$
The approximate formula gives $I\approx 1.02895$
The absolute deviation from the exact value is $0.007765$
